# How exactly did Ron and Hermione get out of the Chamber of Secrets during the Battle of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

Ron and Hermione went down into the Chamber of Secrets during the Battle of Hogwarts to collect Basilisk fangs. They could get inside by mimicked parseltongue and gravity, but how could they get out?

Last time they went inside (second year), there was a Phoenix on the campus to carry them out, but how did they get out this time? The Chamber of Secrets was so deep underground (possibly below that lake outside).

Comment: Are you asking about the books or the movies?

Comment: In Book2, JKR conrrived a situation where they were left without broomsticks or wands (Ron's wand was broken, Harry's was taken by Tom Riddle, Hermione's was taken by Lockhart), plus they were second-years. In Book7, none of that applies. How did they get out? Probably the same way Slytherin, the Gaunts, Tom Riddle, the basilisk, and Ginny (presumably she entered the Chamber at some point while under the influence of the diary to let the basilisk out) did. It was the Chamber of Secrets, not the Chamber of No Way Out.

Comment: @Acccumulation I’m now picturing Slytherin just straddling his basilisk and riding it through the pipes :D

Comment: @Acccumulation Basilisk was a giant snake which could find its way through holes and pipes. Talking about others, they could ride the Basilisk like the previous comment said. There's nothing funny about it.

Comment: @The Wasp So you're suggesting that any time any of them visited the chamber, they rode the basilisk out, then sent the basilisk back? Did the basilisk close the door behind himself?

Comment: @Acccumulation Even muggle technologies are in existence to auto close the doors behind. This is magic world we are talking about.

Comment: @The Wasp Yeah, sure, it's *possible*, but it's bumping against Occam's Razor. One hypothesis is that they all controlled the basilisk, attached themselves to it, rode it through the pipes without being knocked off, sent the basilisk back, then closed the door remotely. Another hypothesis is that they rode a broomstick.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

They used a broomstick to get out. I’m sure broomsticks would not be difficult to obtain during the chaos of the battle.

> And then he skidded round a final corner and with a yell of mingled
>   relief and fury he saw them: Ron and Hermione, both with their arms
>   full of large, curved, dirty yellow objects, **Ron with a broomstick
>   under his arm**.
>
> *Harry Potter and The Deathly Hallows, Chapter 31 The Battle of
>   Hogwarts (emphasis mine)*

Comment: I wonder how they piloted the broom in pipes.

Comment: @TheWasp they didn't need to go up the pipes to get out of the chamber, when they escaped the chamber with the help of Fawkes the Phoenix in Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, they flew out of an opening created by the chamber caving in as a result of Lockharts failed memory charm. Therefore they probably just flew out of the cave opening like last time.

Comment: @DannyJames Did they not fix that hole between book 2 and book 7?  Seems like something the school would want patched up before students get back.

Comment: A hole in a secret chamber that no one but 4 students and the headmaster know about? Also that only 2 (perhaps 3 if Ron’s imitations are accurate enough) of which have the ability to access?

Comment: @DannyJames That's not true if we're talking about the books (and we should be, the movies are nonsense). The Chamber of Secrets is, by the estimation of Harry and Ron, miles under the school (possibly under the lake). A cave-in sufficient to block the passageway wouldn't necessarily result in a hole they could actually exit through, especially if it is underneath the lake. They return to the school the same way they came in - the pipe leading to/from Moaning Myrtle's bathroom.

Comment: @TheWasp It's a pipe large enough for a giant snake to travel through, so there should be room for a broom and rider(s). Provided you flew slowly, and had light so you could see the turns (the passenger could hold up their wand after casting Lumos), there shouldn't really be any issues.